# Database system to store lots of large dictionaries

Tags: nosql

I have an application requirement to store a large amount of dictionaries in a database for fast reading. I know beforehand the approximate size and number of data that needs to be stored. The requirement is as follows:

- Store around 100.000 dictionaries or hash tables (for fast access to each value in dictionary)
- Each dictionary/hash table can have up to 10.000 key/value pairs

Why am I thinking of dictionaries? Because I need lightning fast reads, I can cope with slow writes, as the writes are going to happen offline, but data needs to be read as fast as possible (used for a search engine). My first thought was to use a key/value store, because each dictionary has a unique keyword associated to it. The following is an example of the data that needs to be stored and read efficiently:

```
"house": {
             "12345322": 0.467,
             "33627312": 0.657,
             "88349823": 0.342,
             ... (up to 10.000 unique keys here)
         },

"car": {
           "12345322": 0.378,
           "33627312": 0.851,
           "88349823": 0.266,
           ... (up to 10.000 unique keys here)
       },
... up to 100.000 dictionaries (unique keys)
```

Currently I am looking for the right tool to solve this problem. What database system do you recommend? I have a pair of tools that come to mind (Redis) but I do not know if they are adequate for this amount of data.

Comment: Wjhy not a RDBMS?

Comment: I thought about it but to store this data in a SQL table it would have 100.000 * 10.000 = 1.000.000.000 (1 billion) rows. Don't know how this would perform even with proper indices

Comment: If you store it in Redis, it would still be 1 billion key/values pairs, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes, it would still be 1 billion key/value pairs